# Can't login to MySQL as root anymore?

Tags: 15.04, mysql, mariadb

It looks like I can not login to MySQL (actually MariaDB) as root user anymore in Ubuntu 15.04 (I upgraded from 14.04 via 14.10)

I already tried to reset the password.

What *is* working, is `sudo mysql` - but I want to login as root from an other user using `mysql -uroot -p`. When I create a new user with full rights and password, it is working.

Was there something changed?

Comment: ehm ... "but I want to login as root" To me(!) there never has been a reason for this. You can set the system up for any other user than root and do the same from that user if you want to ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind Plenty of reason to log in as root *in a database*. It's the only way to manage users, databases, etc. There's no internal sudo mechanism.

Comment: @oli we use another user for that. ie. access with "root" is only possible when using "sudo su" to reset mysql but that one does not require any authentication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So [you've gone](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mariadb-server&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) from version `5.5.44-1ubuntu0.14.04.1` to `10.0.20-0ubuntu0.15.04.1`. Sounds scarier than it is, that's just [what they called 5.6 for some reason](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/what-is-mariadb-100/).

It seems that newer versions of MariaDB have added a plugin to the user table to force authentication through a fixed path. In this case, the `root` database user is forced through [the `unix_socket` plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/). This also seems to be known as `auth_socket` in some circles.

Anyway this plugin restricts things so only the system `root` user can log in as the database `root`, with no password. It's a security choice they've made.

You can revert this by [blanking the plugin field for the `root` user](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275033&p=13272227#post13272227):

```
shell$ sudo mysql -u root

[mysql] use mysql;
[mysql] update user set plugin='' where User='root';
[mysql] flush privileges;
```

A specified password should work after this. I'm not sure how advisable this is though.

Comment: After this, the login via `sudo mysql -u root` is not possible anymore. That means, the `/etc/mysql/debian.conf` should also be adapted.

Comment: Did not work for me. After this I could not even login with 'sudo mysql -u root' anymore.