# MySQL how to log into "root" from a user account after upgade to 5.7

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql

Running Ubuntu Server 14.04, installed MySQL 5.7 using the MySQL APT Repository. I cannot access MySQL using the "root" user from a user account (`$`) but I can with `sudo` or `sudo su -` (`#`). The MySQL "root" user is working, of course - I *can* log in as `root` (`#`) with my password.

All MySQL configuration other than the custom "root" password is defaults. The "root" password is updated as `# echo "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQLPASS'" | mysql`.

Both the above command and installing MySQL are done automatically as provisioning steps, if that influences the defaults at all. I was able to log in to MySQL from `$` using "root" prior to the upgrade, but I'm not seeing any MySQL specific changes related to this.

How can I log into MySQL's as "root" from a user account again?

Comment: Looks related, though a different database http://askubuntu.com/q/672008/427339

Comment: Hmmm, "Can access with `root` (`UID 0`)"," cannot with `non-root` (`UID > 0`)" says "file ownership/permission problem". It could be on your database, or on the MySQL binaries, or elsewhere. Without the error message you get when "I cannot access MySQL" happens, we can offer little else.

Comment: @waltinator: `ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` - I believe you were right about a file permission problem - the answer I found involves removing socket based authentication.

Answer (score 3):

- stop mysql server (`service mysql stop` or `ps aux | grep mysql` to determine the PID and then `kill -9 PID`)
- `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`
- `UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE User = 'root'` to fix the root PW not working
- `update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('YOURNEWPASSWORD') where user='root';`
- `killall -9 mysqld_safe`
- `service mysql start`

Comment: I don't need to fix the root password not working - the root password works fine, as stated in my question. I also have no desire to change the root password, as I am generating and setting it.

Comment: I have had the trouble that suddenly my mysql password was unset. Also in 5.7 the password setting procedure changed (field `password` was renamed to `authentication_string` as far as it seemed to me), thus I included the information on how to change it. Using the `--init-file` parameter or using `ALTER USER` did not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE User = 'root'` *before* the "`ALTER USER ...`" command which sets the password, then `flush privileges`.

Comment: Nope, worked at the command line, not working to provision.

Comment: Gave up, using `sudo mysql` moving forward.